# Session_Start doesn't work in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

In my Global.cs ,

```
namespace HitCounters
{
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    private static int totalNumberOfUsers = 0;
    private static int currentNumberOfUsers = 0;

    protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        totalNumberOfUsers += 1;
        currentNumberOfUsers += 1;
    }

    protected void Session_End(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        currentNumberOfUsers -= 1;
    }

    protected void Application_End(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public static int TotalNumberOfUsers
    {
        get
        {
            return totalNumberOfUsers;
        }
    }

    public static int CurrentNumberOfUsers
    {
        get
        {
            return currentNumberOfUsers;
        }
    } 


 }
 }
```

And , at the page_Load of Master Page ,

```
    countOnline.Text = HitCounters.Global.CurrentNumberOfUsers.ToString();
    countVisitor.Text = HitCounters.Global.TotalNumberOfUsers.ToString();
```

I think Session_Start doesn't work . 
The total Visitor count and online user count always show number zero .
I want to know why ! Am i missing something ?

Comment: your code is not thread safe. add a lock around the increment and decrement or use interlocked increment.

Comment: I reference this link > http://imar.spaanjaars.com/223/howto-create-a-hit-counter-using-the-globalasax-file-in-aspnet-1x

Comment: Are you using Session in your application?

Comment: does not matter, wrong is wrong :-) does not explain why your breakpoint is not hit. btw. the idea makes not really sense at all :)

Answer (score 0):

Configure `<sessionState>` in your Web.config .